# How to access a firebase field in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have the following code:

```
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let username2 = user?.username
        self.username?.text = username2
```

Although where it says user?. I get a bunch of options that pop up like phone number, email, displayName, providerId, etc although the option for username doesn't pop up. Here is my firebase:
[image]
I would say I'm not accessing the fields the right way although the option for uid pops up. When I type in username though it says

```
Value of type 'User' has no member 'username'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let uid = user?.uid
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid!)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                let username2 = document?.get("username")
                self.username?.text = username2 as? String
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Auth.auth().currentUser` in your code determines the user that is signed in with Firebase Authentication.

The screenshot in your question shows a document in the Cloud Firestore database.

While both products are part of Firebase, you can't access documents in Firestore through the Firebase Authentication API.

If you want to access the document in your screenshot, use the Firestore API that is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

To [load the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) for the user that is currently signed in to Firebase Authentication, that'd be something like:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let uid = user.uid

let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let username2 = document.get("username")
        ...
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

---

*Update** I now noticed that you have the UID of the user **inside** the document. In that case you need to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to find the document(s) that match the UID value:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let username2 = document.get("username")
                self.username?.text = username2 as? String
            }
        }
}
```

Since in this case there may be multiple documents with the UID, so you'll have to loop and deal with that.

Please also read the links that I added, as most of this is copy/paste from there and my Swift knowledge is not great.

Comment: I just updated my answer to the code that I added although nothing shows up then when I run build my project.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that you have the UID in a field. I added an example of how to qeury for the document in that case. Note